# Recalculating height of waypoint elements on window resize

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-waypoints

I used the jQuery Waypoints plugin in conjunction with a fixed menu on a one page website. The menu consists of an up and down arrow, as the waypoint is passed I use jQuery to change the link in the up and down arrow to the next or previous page. When the button is pressed, I use jQuery scroll to scroll to that page. It works pretty well, and I'm not sure I've seen jQuery waypoints used in this way before. Thanks for your great plugin!

However, I'm trying to make my site totally responsive, and I'm having one issue with what I think is the refresh of the waypoint information. When the window is resized, the height of the pages (which is being calculated when the waypoints are defined) is not changing. This results in an incorrect scroll distance.

I'm a student, and my code is a bit messy, and probably a bit inefficient but a beta version of my site can be seen here: http://beta.kyleboulay.com

Again, just to be clear: the problem occurs when you resize the window after the page first loads, the distances are not re-calculated properly.

**EDIT:** I seem to have somewhat fixed the problem by changing the offset value of the way points to 50%. But, it would still be great to know how to trigger the redefinition of the waypoints on window resize.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

The following is an example of my code.

I define my waypoints like this:

```
//first get all the pages // this returns my six pages

sections = $(".pages");

//then define what happens as each waypoint is passed, depending on the direction**

$(sections[5]).waypoint({

    handler: function(event, direction){

                //console.log('5');
                distanceDown = $(sections[5]).offset().top;
                distanceUp =  $(sections[4]).offset().top;

                if(direction==='up'){

                    //console.log('5 up');
                    distanceDown = $(sections[5]).offset().top;
                    distanceUp =  $(sections[3]).offset().top;

                }

    },

    offset: '50%'

});

//then when the down or up button is pressed on the menu, i do the following:

$('#icon-up').click(function(){

$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: distanceUp }, { duration: slideSpeed, easing: 'swing' });

});//end inline
```